# python package panda not working opensuse leap 42.3

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I installed opensuse leap 42.3. Python 2.7.13 was also installed with it. I tried to install pandas and various other packages by

```
pip install pandas
```

It installed pandas for python 3.4 which is not installed in my system. So python programs with

```
import pandas
```

is not running with python 2.7
What should I do now ? Uninstalling python2.7 is not recommended as it came with os. If I install python 3.4, how should I avoid conflicts between two pythons while compiling any program.

Comment: The module is called `pandas`, with an `s`

Comment: oh.. sorry its typo. corrected.

Comment: Huh, I stand corrected, there's also a `panda` module

Comment: In this case you really need to be sure whether it's `panda` or `pandas` that was installed

Comment: anyways it is not issue, issue is with python version. similar problem happened while pip installing matplotlib

Comment: i intended pandas for importing xlsx files

Comment: please give specific reply. I asked how to avoid conflict between two pythons ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your installation, you could try installing with pip2 instead of with pip.
This should specifiy that the installation refers to python 2.x, similar to how pip3 refers to python 3.x versions.

Thus use

```
pip2 install pandas
```

Using pip just defaults to one of these versions (most likely 3.x), which can result in unwanted behaviour. Although it is unlikely that this was the default if python 3.4 was not installed. Are you sure that this is the case?

This is mainly convention, so it is possible that it might not work on your device unfortunately.

To answer the second part of your question, [conda](https://conda.io/docs/) is an excellent package manager/virtual environment that allow you to install and use as many different versions of python, with as many different packages as you want.

Comment: Thanks Ivo ! pip2 is not working for matplotlib 2.1.0. For pip2 install matplotlib 2.1.0 , it is looking for matplotlib-3.0.1 latest version.

Comment: Have you tried running pip2 install matplotlib==2.1.0 ?